# When using docker images in Gitlab CI, how do I deference the alias of a service

Tags: docker, gitlab, alias

Below is an excerpt from my gitlab-ci.yml file. Simply put I need to create a redis service, and then reference it as it is required for testing.

Because the redis server is created dynamically I don't know of an easy way to tell it to look at 'localhost' or 123.321.234.234 etc.

Is there a way to deference an alias of a service such as the one created below so that its value can be passed into another container so they can 'talk'? In my code I'm attempting to reference the 'redis' alias and feed that value into an environment variable during the pipeline but it turns into a literal string.

I've also tried ${redis} and this fails likewise.

The furthest I've gotten was what I've read from the gitlab documentation on Anchors, of which I have below.

Below are the places I've looked for answers

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html

```
# the image and gitlab services to use in the build stages
.build-web-image: &build-web-image
 image: Dontworryaboutit.com:4567/folder/dockerImage:1.0.0
 services:
  - name: redis:3.2.8
    alias: redis

# The job that runs the yarn run test that requires a redis server
Test Web:
 <<: *build-web-image
 stage: Stage 2
 before_script:
  - export REDIS=redis:1234
  - yarn
 script:
  - yarn run test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aliases can be dereferenced by referring to their string name with no extra decorations like

```
${variable}
```

You can just type

```
 variable
```

Make sure to check your config.toml file to ensure that the docker executor is being used for that runner. It's an easy mistake to make when switching CI/CD strategies.